# Is the usage of "Inform sb to do sth" right?

Tags: word-usage

I will *inform* the supplier to produce the sample sticker if you don’t have any requirements.

Is there the usage of *inform sb to do sth* in English?

Comment: Hi. Not really. It's not the right verb. It's a bit strange/odd.  Use "ask/tell someone to do something" instead.  "Inform" generally means to give someone information, which doesn't quite make sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No we can't.

There are several ways to use **inform**, but we don't use **inform sb to do sth**.<sup>[[1]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/inform)</sup>

- **inform sb about sth** - The leaflet **informs** customers **about** healthy eating (From [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/))<sup>[[2]](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/inform)</sup>
- **inform sb of sth** - They would inform him of any progress they had made. (From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/))<sup>[[3]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inform)</sup>
- **inform sb that** - He informed me that Judy won't come to the party tonight. (Example by myself)
- **keep sb informed** - I want to know what you decide, so keep me informed. (From [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/))<sup>[[4]](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/keep-somebody-informed)</sup>

<sub>P.S. Attributions are included in the links</sub>